# How to install a web2py site from a github project

Tags: web2py

I'm interested in installing [this site](https://github.com/ilvalle/vtraffic) into my web2py installation. I've used the github "download zip" and extracted it to the `/web2py/applications/` directory in my web2py install and restarted web2py, but it's not appearing on my admin page.

Looking through the web2py structure I can't see any obvious config files that tell the framework what pages to load.

So how do you install applications that don't come in a .w2p file?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extract those application folders/files into a folder within your /applications folder. So the structure would look like:

```
/web2py/applications/myapp/controllers
/web2py/applications/myapp/cron
/web2py/applications/myapp/languages
etc.
```

Comment: Hi. That's exactly what I've done already, but to no effect; hence this question.

Comment: OK, but that's how it works, so there must be something else wrong. Hard to say without more information. What did you name the app folder?

Comment: Ah, got it. Apparently having a "-" (hyphen) in the name was stopping it from showing up (github calls things "-master" or whatever). Thanks!